# Use a method over and over again or save the result as a property, what's faster/better?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm currently learning OOP in JS.

First off, here's the code:

```
this.device = {
    init: function(){
        this.isiOS7 = (this._isiOS7()) ? true : false; 
    },
    _isiOS7 : function(){
        return (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone);.*CPU.*OS 7_\d/i)) ? true : false;
    },
    isiOS7 : null
}
```

As you can see, I defined a property named isiOS7 and a function _isiOS7. The main idea behind this is: whenever I needed to know whether the OS is iOS7, I'd access a property (isiOS7) which is true or false. If I'd use the function (_isiOS7) over and over again it would take longer for the JS engine to compute these statements(if/regex/match) than a simple property/var. So my question is: Is this true?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably the most quoted programming aphorism ever: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you are just trying to get the window navigator. So it's better to run init once and use an accessor for the property.

Although this will hardly matter unless this is supposed to be called often.